# Concrete 5.7(+) style customizer not working on custom theme

Tags: php, xml, less, concrete5

I am doing my best to learn concrete 5 by developing a site. So I have created my empty basic theme, and have attempted to implement a single variable via the styles customizer - just to see that I understand how it works. The bottom line is that I am getting the customize button on my theme, but upon click, the new display that opens is empty - no variable, no set titles, no back button.

Was hoping someone can help me out with this, no local community to ask, don't know anyone personally too - so it is kinda all on you :]

So, my code.

Theme is called 'carmi', lives in the 'carmi' folder under 'themes' in the application directory. 
has a CSS directory with template.less, styles.xml, and index.html. Also has a typography.less which is not in use.

inside the css directory is a presets directory with two less files: 'defaults' and 'testPreset'. Both have at least one variable.

for page templates I have default, front, full, and view, all of which with the exact same code (except view).

I test the code on a page (not a single), tried several page types.

code in default. php:

```
<?php

defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die ('you shall not pass');

$bodyClass = ($c->isEditMode() ? 'editMode' : '');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php Loader::element('header_required'); ?>

    <link href="<?php echo $view->getStylesheet('template.less');?>"  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <?php
    //echo $html->css($view->getStylesheet('less/styles.less'));

    ?>
</head>

<body class="<?php echo $bodyClass; ?>" >
    <?php $this->inc('elements/test.php');?>
    <div class="test-class">test text</div>

    <?php $a = new GlobalArea('Site Header'); $a->display();?>
    <?php $a = new Area('Test'); $a->display($c);?>

    <?php Loader::element('footer_required'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

The test.php element is just some text to prove a point.

code in template.less

```
@import "presets/defaults.less";

*{
    color: @primary-action-color;
}

.test-class {
    color: @another-color;
}
```

code in defaults.less note that this did not work also without the 3 first variables.

```
@preset-name: "test";
@preset-icon: concrete-icon(#ffffff, #ff7600, #333333);
@preset-fonts-file: "fonts/defaults.less";

@primary-action-color: #ff7600;
@another-color: #aaaaaa;
```

code in styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<styles version="1.0">
    <set name="test">
        <style name="Primary Action Color" variable="primary-action" type="color" />
    </set>
</styles>
```

code in testPreset.less

```
@primary-action-color: #aaaaaa;
@another-color: #ff7600;
```

the less is parsed into the page. I can see it working properly with it's imported variables. But nothing on the customize panel.

Thank you so much if you chose to take the time to read all of this. I was sitting on this for a long time and got quite frustrated :[

Answer (score 1):

I have got some help in the concrete forum. It seems that the defaults.less @preset-name must be "Default". I have not gotten official response from the developer  but, that worked for me as well as for the person offering the help on the forum.